# CakePHP 4, PhpStorm and PHPStan object class confusion

Tags: php, cakephp, phpunit, phpstorm

I tried asking this question once, a while ago. Unfortunately, I sort of let the thread run dead so I'm trying again:
[CakePHP Entity vs EntityInterface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72189117/cakephp-entity-vs-entityinterface)

I'm also a little more familiar with the problem so as to ask a more accurate question.

I'm developing an application using PhpStorm as my IDE. The application additionally runs the standard-issue pre-commit checks of grammar and the like with a combination of PHPCS, PHPUnit and PHPStan. As you are probably familiar, PhpStorm can also check your code while you develop. Somehow, between CakePHP, PhpStorm and PHPUnit there seems to be a lot of confusion with how data is returned from the model and how that data is interpreted.

Consider the following code snippet:

```
$user = $this->Orders->Users->get($user->getIdentifier());
$cart = $this->Orders->Carts
    ->find('complete')
    ->where(['id' => $cart_id])
    ->first();
$this->checkForItems($cart);
```

PhpStorm immediately flags that last function call because, as it says:

```
Expected parameter of type '\Visualize\Model\Entity\Cart', 'array|\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface|null' provided
```

Indeed, I am expecting a Cart entity in my code:

```
/**
 * @param Cart $cart The current shopping cart
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function checkForItems(Cart $cart) {
    if (empty($cart->cart_lines)) {
        throw new InternalErrorException('There are no line items in this cart');
    }
}
```

**BUT** - *and this is critical* - if I do `get_class` on the `$cart` object I just created, it tells me that this is a `Visualize\Model\Entity\Order`.

So I'm a bit confused by this turn of events. If indeed the objects created ARE Order objects, why can PHPUnit not figure that out? Is there some documentation I'm missing in my code that might otherwise resolve the confusion?

This confusion severely hampers production, because if I validate that an object is an `EntityInterface` then PHPUnit will not recognize fields from the database as existing in the object, because of course the `EntityInterface` does not have those fields. I'm constantly having to juggle definitions to make things work.

Answer (score 1):

That is the expected behavior, keep in mind that this is *static* analysis, what finally happens at *runtime* is to a certain degree unknown to the analyzer!

`first()` is a method of the generic result set class, it doesn't know what concrete entity type might be returned, also it must account for the fact that the data might be an array instead of an entity (when hydration is disabled for the query), so `first()` correctly says that its return value is either `array`, `\Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface`, or `null`.

Now you're passing that value to a method that only accepts `\Visualize\Model\Entity\Order`, so analyzers will complain (rightfully so), because neither of the possible return types of `first()` can satisfy that contract (`Order` is an `EntityInterface`, but not every `EntityInterface` is an `Order`).

To satisfy the static analysis you need to add some form of hint before passing the value to your `checkForItems()` method, for example an assertion:

```php
assert($cart instanceof \Visualize\Model\Entity\Order);
```

or an inline type hint:

```php
/** @var \Visualize\Model\Entity\Order $cart */
```

See also

**https://phpstan.org/writing-php-code/phpdocs-basics#inline-%40var**

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you. I will start reading and implementing. You're always a big help, NDM.

Comment: One correction: `\Visualize\Model\Entity\Order|null $cart` if you use first() instead of firstOrFail() ;) Then PHPStan will also tell you about this code being badly written, as it doesnt check for the "null" case yet.